# Getting all of BIND 9.9's messages to go to the logging file

Tags: bind

Is there a way to get all of BIND's startup messages to go into the log named in the config file? For example, in named.conf, I have:

```
logging {
    channel qlog {
        file "/etc/bind/named.log";
        severity debug 2;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-category yes;
    };
    category default { qlog; };
};
```

The "default" category is supposed to get all of the logging that doesn't happen in other categories. However, when I start named, I get a bunch of messages in /var/log/daemon.log, and then more in the named file. I would like them all to go into the named file so I don't have to look two places to figure out what might have gone wrong when starting.

Answer (score 1):

From the [logging section in the BIND manual](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2575001):

> In BIND 9, the logging configuration is only established when the
>   entire configuration file has been parsed. In BIND 8, it was
>   established as soon as the logging statement was parsed. When the
>   server is starting up, all logging messages regarding syntax errors in
>   the configuration file go to the default channels, or to standard
>   error if the "-g" option was specified.

This limitation is not normally a problem as `named-checkconf -zj` (or other variation of configuration check that you have as part of your regular workflow) will catch any syntactical errors long before you have (re)started `named`.

As more of a sidenote, your choice of path for the log file (`/etc/bind/named.log`) comes across as rather peculiar. Generally you wouldn't want to have log files in `/etc`, or have `/etc/bind` writable by the user running the service for that matter.